# How to make a shallow copy of entire structure?

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure that holds another structure, a linked list and a flexible array member. I want to make a shallow copy of this entire structure. What is the fastest way I can do this without loosing any of the components? By this I mean all of the malloced memory for the linked list.

This is the structure I would like copied.

```
struct Student{
        char *name;
        int age;
        Courses *list;  //First course (node) of linked list
        Student *friends[];  //Flexible array member
    }Student;
```

Edit: Question mentioned as possible duplicate is for a simple structure and does not mention anything about how to deal with linked lists etx.